# Creating human time like It is five minutes to twelve in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, associative-array

> *I'm but a humble IT student, one of our current projects is to create a clock with **PHP, HTML and CSS**, that displays time in text that also can say when it's "half past" or "five minutes to" or "quarter past" etc. etc.*

Something that would display something along the lines of:

> "It is five minutes to twelve"

**I am using Notepad++, a local server host and my browser for this.**

I have been using what I've learned about very basic stuff like: for, while and if loops, variables, operators in php. That. Is. It.

I did myself a favour and read about **associative arrays** as i found that, *in my mind anyways*, this was a nice way to transfer the integers that date(); sends out, to strings associated to those integers with the function foreach();

***This is what that would look like:***

```
<?php

    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Oslo'); // Set default time zone
    $time = time(); // API(?) for time
    $clock = date("H:i:s", $time); //create a variable $clock for 24hour(H), minutes(i) and seconds(s) in relation to $time
    echo "<title> $clock </title>"; //set time as page title 
    header("Refresh:0"); //this refreshes the page and honestly is about the worst solution i could find to have page title update as time passes, but it works so whatever
    echo "<h1>$clock</h1> <br>"; //prints time as a h1 with html
    
    $hour = date("H"); //these three lines assign variables to each of the time functions 
    $minute = date("i");    
    $second = date("s");

    $hisArray = array("One"=>"1", "Two"=>"2", "Three"=>"3", "Four"=>"4", "Five"=>"5", "Six"=>"6", "Seven"=>"7", "Eight"=>"8", "Nine"=>"9", "Ten"=>"10", "Eleven"=>"11", "Twelve"=>"12", "Thirteen"=>"13", "Fourteen"=>"14","Fifteen"=>"15", "Sixteen"=>"16","Seventeen"=>"17", "Eighteen"=>"18", "Nineteen"=>"19", "Twenty"=>"20", "Twenty-one"=>"21", "Twenty-Two"=>"22","Twenty-Three" =>"23", "Twenty-Four" =>"24", "Twenty-Five"=>"25", "Twenty-Six"=>"26", "Twenty-Seven"=>"27", "Twenty-Eight"=>"28", "Twenty-Nine"=>"29", "Thirty"=>"30", "Thirty-One"=>"31", "Thirty-Two"=>"32", "Thirty-Three"=>"33", "Thirty-Four"=>"34", "Thirty-Five"=>"35", "Thirty-Six"=>"36", "Thirty-Seven"=>"37", "Thirty-Eight"=>"38", "Thirty-Nine"=>"39", "Fourty"=>"40", "Fourty-one"=>"41", "Fourty-two"=>"42", "Fourty-three"=>"43", "Fourty-four"=>"44", "Fourty-five"=>"45", "Fourty-six"=>"46", "Fourty-seven"=>"47", "Fourty-eight"=>"48", "Fourty-nine"=>"49", "Fifty"=>"50", "Fifty-one"=>"51", "Fifty-two"=>"52", "Fifty-three"=>"53", "Fifty-four"=>"54", "Fifty-five"=>"55", "Fifty-six"=>"56", "Fifty-seven"=>"57", "Fifty-eight"=>"58", "Fifty-nine"=>"59"); 
//array with numbers needed to convert the integer date(); sends out to a string associated with it. 
    
    foreach($hisArray as $h => $h_value) { //foreach() splits into two variable from the $hisArray in line 21 ($h is str og $h_value is int)
        if($h_value == $hour){ //this if loop is run if h_value is equal to the current hour, making it so the string version of the current hour number is displayed
            echo "it is $h hours, "; 
        }
    }
?>
```

This *only* prints out the *current* hour of the day, I have, basically identical, code that works for seconds as well. **I made this work with minutes too**. That being said, i still want the program to know *whenever half an hour has passed since the last full hour*. So that "it is half past ..." can be printed out.

This is what I am struggling with, I've tried writing some **abysmal** and **likely sacrilegious** if...elseif..elseif...elseif code, but I really don't like this approach. And on top of the constantly refreshing page I don't imagine 50 lines of if... statements is going to impact the load time *positively* when we start using CSS to make things look good.

I would like to hear literally anything that could be of use here, ***help.***

If there is anything about the little bit of script I've showed here that you have an opinion about feel free to tell me about that too :)

Comment: Please keep more focus. Your code does not contain any "abysmal" parts, so it's pretty difficult to see where you wentr wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is quite a bit to fix it, you definitely don't want to use a ton of if/else's..

Because the time strings are not in 24 hour clock, I would use `h` format over `H`, then the rest is just matching the current minute with the closest time string for that hour, then build the string using the hour, and due to the *Its twelve o'clock* oddity, it would need to be a template also when its 40 mins past the hour you would need to increment the hour but only if it's not 12, simplez ;p

This is what i've come up with:

```
function humanTime($hour, $min) {
    $times = [
        0 => '%s o\'clock',
        2 => 'couple of mins past %s',
        5 => 'five past %s',
        8 => 'around ten past %s',
        10 => 'ten past %s',
        15 => 'quarter past %s',
        20 => 'twenty past %s',
        25 => 'twenty five past %s',
        27 => 'around half past %s',
        30 => 'half past %s',
        33 => 'around thirty five past %s',
        35 => 'thirty five past %s',
        40 => 'twenty to %s',
        43 => 'around quarter to %s',
        45 => 'quarter to %s',
        47 => 'about ten to %s',
        50 => 'ten to %s',
        53 => 'about five to %s',
        55 => 'five to %s'
    ];
    
    $hourWord = [
        'one',
        'two',
        'three',
        'four',
        'five',
        'six',
        'seven',
        'eight',
        'nine',
        'ten',
        'eleven',
        'twelve'
    ];

    $hour = (int) $hour;
    $min = (int) $min;
    
    $closest = null;
    foreach ($times as $key => $item) 
        if ($closest === null || abs($min - $closest) > abs($key - $min)) $closest = $key;
    
    if ($hour === 0) $hour = 12;
    
    if ($min > 40) $hour = $hour === 12 ? 1 : $hour + 1;

    return sprintf($times[$closest], $hourWord[(int) $hour - 1]);
}
```

Then simply pass in the hour and min (concatenating *Its* because that could also be optional):

```
echo 'It\'s ' . humanTime(date('h'), date('i')).PHP_EOL;
```

**Test which goes through the entire day:**

https://3v4l.org/7rV89

```
Time: 00:00
It's twelve o'clock
Time: 00:01
It's twelve o'clock
Time: 00:02
It's couple of mins past twelve
Time: 00:03
It's couple of mins past twelve
Time: 00:04
It's five past twelve
Time: 00:05
It's five past twelve
Time: 00:06
It's five past twelve
Time: 00:07
It's around ten past twelve
Time: 00:08
It's around ten past twelve
Time: 00:09
It's around ten past twelve
Time: 00:10
It's ten past twelve
Time: 00:11
It's ten past twelve
Time: 00:12
It's ten past twelve
Time: 00:13
It's quarter past twelve
Time: 00:14
It's quarter past twelve
Time: 00:15
It's quarter past twelve
Time: 00:16
It's quarter past twelve
Time: 00:17
It's quarter past twelve
Time: 00:18
It's twenty past twelve
Time: 00:19
It's twenty past twelve
Time: 00:20
It's twenty past twelve
Time: 00:21
It's twenty past twelve
Time: 00:22
It's twenty past twelve
Time: 00:23
It's twenty five past twelve
Time: 00:24
It's twenty five past twelve
Time: 00:25
It's twenty five past twelve
Time: 00:26
It's twenty five past twelve
Time: 00:27
It's around half past twelve
Time: 00:28
It's around half past twelve
Time: 00:29
It's half past twelve
Time: 00:30
It's half past twelve
Time: 00:31
It's half past twelve
Time: 00:32
It's around thirty five past twelve
Time: 00:33
It's around thirty five past twelve
Time: 00:34
It's around thirty five past twelve
Time: 00:35
It's thirty five past twelve
Time: 00:36
It's thirty five past twelve
Time: 00:37
It's thirty five past twelve
Time: 00:38
It's twenty to twelve
Time: 00:39
It's twenty to twelve
Time: 00:40
It's twenty to twelve
Time: 00:41
It's twenty to one
Time: 00:42
It's around quarter to one
Time: 00:43
It's around quarter to one
Time: 00:44
It's around quarter to one
Time: 00:45
It's quarter to one
Time: 00:46
It's quarter to one
Time: 00:47
It's about ten to one
Time: 00:48
It's about ten to one
Time: 00:49
It's ten to one
Time: 00:50
It's ten to one
Time: 00:51
It's ten to one
Time: 00:52
It's about five to one
Time: 00:53
It's about five to one
Time: 00:54
It's about five to one
Time: 00:55
It's five to one
Time: 00:56
It's five to one
Time: 00:57
It's five to one
Time: 00:58
It's five to one
Time: 00:59
It's five to one
Time: 01:00
It's one o'clock
Time: 01:01
It's one o'clock
Time: 01:02
It's couple of mins past one
Time: 01:03
It's couple of mins past one
Time: 01:04
It's five past one
Time: 01:05
It's five past one
Time: 01:06
It's five past one
Time: 01:07
It's around ten past one
Time: 01:08
It's around ten past one
Time: 01:09
It's around ten past one
Time: 01:10
It's ten past one
Time: 01:11
It's ten past one
Time: 01:12
It's ten past one
Time: 01:13
It's quarter past one
Time: 01:14
It's quarter past one
Time: 01:15
It's quarter past one
Time: 01:16
It's quarter past one
Time: 01:17
It's quarter past one
Time: 01:18
It's twenty past one
Time: 01:19
It's twenty past one
Time: 01:20
It's twenty past one
Time: 01:21
It's twenty past one
Time: 01:22
It's twenty past one
Time: 01:23
It's twenty five past one
Time: 01:24
It's twenty five past one
Time: 01:25
It's twenty five past one
Time: 01:26
It's twenty five past one
Time: 01:27
It's around half past one
Time: 01:28
It's around half past one
Time: 01:29
It's half past one
Time: 01:30
It's half past one
Time: 01:31
It's half past one
Time: 01:32
It's around thirty five past one
Time: 01:33
It's around thirty five past one
Time: 01:34
It's around thirty five past one
Time: 01:35
It's thirty five past one
Time: 01:36
It's thirty five past one
Time: 01:37
It's thirty five past one
Time: 01:38
It's twenty to one
Time: 01:39
It's twenty to one
Time: 01:40
It's twenty to one
Time: 01:41
It's twenty to two
Time: 01:42
It's around quarter to two
Time: 01:43
It's around quarter to two
Time: 01:44
It's around quarter to two
Time: 01:45
It's quarter to two
Time: 01:46
It's quarter to two
Time: 01:47
It's about ten to two
Time: 01:48
It's about ten to two
Time: 01:49
It's ten to two
Time: 01:50
It's ten to two
Time: 01:51
It's ten to two
Time: 01:52
It's about five to two
Time: 01:53
It's about five to two
Time: 01:54
It's about five to two
Time: 01:55
It's five to two
Time: 01:56
It's five to two
Time: 01:57
It's five to two
Time: 01:58
It's five to two
Time: 01:59
It's five to two
Time: 02:00
It's two o'clock
Time: 02:01
It's two o'clock
Time: 02:02
It's couple of mins past two
Time: 02:03
It's couple of mins past two
Time: 02:04
It's five past two
Time: 02:05
It's five past two
Time: 02:06
It's five past two
Time: 02:07
It's around ten past two
Time: 02:08
It's around ten past two
Time: 02:09
It's around ten past two
Time: 02:10
It's ten past two
Time: 02:11
It's ten past two
Time: 02:12
It's ten past two
Time: 02:13
It's quarter past two
Time: 02:14
It's quarter past two
Time: 02:15
It's quarter past two
Time: 02:16
It's quarter past two
Time: 02:17
It's quarter past two
Time: 02:18
It's twenty past two
Time: 02:19
It's twenty past two
Time: 02:20
It's twenty past two
Time: 02:21
It's twenty past two
Time: 02:22
It's twenty past two
Time: 02:23
It's twenty five past two
Time: 02:24
It's twenty five past two
Time: 02:25
It's twenty five past two
Time: 02:26
It's twenty five past two
Time: 02:27
It's around half past two
Time: 02:28
It's around half past two
Time: 02:29
It's half past two
Time: 02:30
It's half past two
Time: 02:31
It's half past two
Time: 02:32
It's around thirty five past two
Time: 02:33
It's around thirty five past two
Time: 02:34
It's around thirty five past two
Time: 02:35
It's thirty five past two
Time: 02:36
It's thirty five past two
Time: 02:37
It's thirty five past two
Time: 02:38
It's twenty to two
Time: 02:39
It's twenty to two
Time: 02:40
It's twenty to two
Time: 02:41
It's twenty to three
Time: 02:42
It's around quarter to three
Time: 02:43
It's around quarter to three
Time: 02:44
It's around quarter to three
Time: 02:45
It's quarter to three
Time: 02:46
It's quarter to three
Time: 02:47
It's about ten to three
Time: 02:48
It's about ten to three
Time: 02:49
It's ten to three
Time: 02:50
It's ten to three
Time: 02:51
It's ten to three
Time: 02:52
It's about five to three
Time: 02:53
It's about five to three
Time: 02:54
It's about five to three
Time: 02:55
It's five to three
Time: 02:56
It's five to three
Time: 02:57
It's five to three
Time: 02:58
It's five to three
Time: 02:59
It's five to three
Time: 03:00
It's three o'clock
Time: 03:01
It's three o'clock
Time: 03:02
It's couple of mins past three
Time: 03:03
It's couple of mins past three
Time: 03:04
It's five past three
Time: 03:05
It's five past three
Time: 03:06
It's five past three
Time: 03:07
It's around ten past three
Time: 03:08
It's around ten past three
Time: 03:09
It's around ten past three
Time: 03:10
It's ten past three
Time: 03:11
It's ten past three
Time: 03:12
It's ten past three
Time: 03:13
It's quarter past three
Time: 03:14
It's quarter past three
Time: 03:15
It's quarter past three
Time: 03:16
It's quarter past three
Time: 03:17
It's quarter past three
Time: 03:18
It's twenty past three
Time: 03:19
It's twenty past three
Time: 03:20
It's twenty past three
Time: 03:21
It's twenty past three
Time: 03:22
It's twenty past three
Time: 03:23
It's twenty five past three
Time: 03:24
It's twenty five past three
Time: 03:25
It's twenty five past three
Time: 03:26
It's twenty five past three
Time: 03:27
It's around half past three
Time: 03:28
It's around half past three
Time: 03:29
It's half past three
Time: 03:30
It's half past three
Time: 03:31
It's half past three
Time: 03:32
It's around thirty five past three
Time: 03:33
It's around thirty five past three
Time: 03:34
It's around thirty five past three
Time: 03:35
It's thirty five past three
Time: 03:36
It's thirty five past three
Time: 03:37
It's thirty five past three
Time: 03:38
It's twenty to three
Time: 03:39
It's twenty to three
Time: 03:40
It's twenty to three
Time: 03:41
It's twenty to four
Time: 03:42
It's around quarter to four
Time: 03:43
It's around quarter to four
Time: 03:44
It's around quarter to four
Time: 03:45
It's quarter to four
Time: 03:46
It's quarter to four
Time: 03:47
It's about ten to four
Time: 03:48
It's about ten to four
Time: 03:49
It's ten to four
Time: 03:50
It's ten to four
Time: 03:51
It's ten to four
Time: 03:52
It's about five to four
Time: 03:53
It's about five to four
Time: 03:54
It's about five to four
Time: 03:55
It's five to four
Time: 03:56
It's five to four
Time: 03:57
It's five to four
Time: 03:58
It's five to four
Time: 03:59
It's five to four
Time: 04:00
It's four o'clock
Time: 04:01
It's four o'clock
Time: 04:02
It's couple of mins past four
Time: 04:03
It's couple of mins past four
Time: 04:04
It's five past four
Time: 04:05
It's five past four
Time: 04:06
It's five past four
Time: 04:07
It's around ten past four
Time: 04:08
It's around ten past four
Time: 04:09
It's around ten past four
Time: 04:10
It's ten past four
Time: 04:11
It's ten past four
Time: 04:12
It's ten past four
Time: 04:13
It's quarter past four
Time: 04:14
It's quarter past four
Time: 04:15
It's quarter past four
Time: 04:16
It's quarter past four
Time: 04:17
It's quarter past four
Time: 04:18
It's twenty past four
Time: 04:19
It's twenty past four
Time: 04:20
It's twenty past four
Time: 04:21
It's twenty past four
Time: 04:22
It's twenty past four
Time: 04:23
It's twenty five past four
Time: 04:24
It's twenty five past four
Time: 04:25
It's twenty five past four
Time: 04:26
It's twenty five past four
Time: 04:27
It's around half past four
Time: 04:28
It's around half past four
Time: 04:29
It's half past four
Time: 04:30
It's half past four
Time: 04:31
It's half past four
Time: 04:32
It's around thirty five past four
Time: 04:33
It's around thirty five past four
Time: 04:34
It's around thirty five past four
Time: 04:35
It's thirty five past four
Time: 04:36
It's thirty five past four
Time: 04:37
It's thirty five past four
Time: 04:38
It's twenty to four
Time: 04:39
It's twenty to four
Time: 04:40
It's twenty to four
Time: 04:41
It's twenty to five
Time: 04:42
It's around quarter to five
Time: 04:43
It's around quarter to five
Time: 04:44
It's around quarter to five
Time: 04:45
It's quarter to five
Time: 04:46
It's quarter to five
Time: 04:47
It's about ten to five
Time: 04:48
It's about ten to five
Time: 04:49
It's ten to five
Time: 04:50
It's ten to five
Time: 04:51
It's ten to five
Time: 04:52
It's about five to five
Time: 04:53
It's about five to five
Time: 04:54
It's about five to five
Time: 04:55
It's five to five
Time: 04:56
It's five to five
Time: 04:57
It's five to five
Time: 04:58
It's five to five
Time: 04:59
It's five to five
Time: 05:00
It's five o'clock
Time: 05:01
It's five o'clock
Time: 05:02
It's couple of mins past five
Time: 05:03
It's couple of mins past five
Time: 05:04
It's five past five
Time: 05:05
It's five past five
Time: 05:06
It's five past five
Time: 05:07
It's around ten past five
Time: 05:08
It's around ten past five
Time: 05:09
It's around ten past five
Time: 05:10
It's ten past five
Time: 05:11
It's ten past five
Time: 05:12
It's ten past five
Time: 05:13
It's quarter past five
Time: 05:14
It's quarter past five
Time: 05:15
It's quarter past five
Time: 05:16
It's quarter past five
Time: 05:17
It's quarter past five
Time: 05:18
It's twenty past five
Time: 05:19
It's twenty past five
Time: 05:20
It's twenty past five
Time: 05:21
It's twenty past five
Time: 05:22
It's twenty past five
Time: 05:23
It's twenty five past five
Time: 05:24
It's twenty five past five
Time: 05:25
It's twenty five past five
Time: 05:26
It's twenty five past five
Time: 05:27
It's around half past five
Time: 05:28
It's around half past five
Time: 05:29
It's half past five
Time: 05:30
It's half past five
Time: 05:31
It's half past five
Time: 05:32
It's around thirty five past five
Time: 05:33
It's around thirty five past five
Time: 05:34
It's around thirty five past five
Time: 05:35
It's thirty five past five
Time: 05:36
It's thirty five past five
Time: 05:37
It's thirty five past five
Time: 05:38
It's twenty to five
Time: 05:39
It's twenty to five
Time: 05:40
It's twenty to five
Time: 05:41
It's twenty to six
Time: 05:42
It's around quarter to six
Time: 05:43
It's around quarter to six
Time: 05:44
It's around quarter to six
Time: 05:45
It's quarter to six
Time: 05:46
It's quarter to six
Time: 05:47
It's about ten to six
Time: 05:48
It's about ten to six
Time: 05:49
It's ten to six
Time: 05:50
It's ten to six
Time: 05:51
It's ten to six
Time: 05:52
It's about five to six
Time: 05:53
It's about five to six
Time: 05:54
It's about five to six
Time: 05:55
It's five to six
Time: 05:56
It's five to six
Time: 05:57
It's five to six
Time: 05:58
It's five to six
Time: 05:59
It's five to six
Time: 06:00
It's six o'clock
Time: 06:01
It's six o'clock
Time: 06:02
It's couple of mins past six
Time: 06:03
It's couple of mins past six
Time: 06:04
It's five past six
Time: 06:05
It's five past six
Time: 06:06
It's five past six
Time: 06:07
It's around ten past six
Time: 06:08
It's around ten past six
Time: 06:09
It's around ten past six
Time: 06:10
It's ten past six
Time: 06:11
It's ten past six
Time: 06:12
It's ten past six
Time: 06:13
It's quarter past six
Time: 06:14
It's quarter past six
Time: 06:15
It's quarter past six
Time: 06:16
It's quarter past six
Time: 06:17
It's quarter past six
Time: 06:18
It's twenty past six
Time: 06:19
It's twenty past six
Time: 06:20
It's twenty past six
Time: 06:21
It's twenty past six
Time: 06:22
It's twenty past six
Time: 06:23
It's twenty five past six
Time: 06:24
It's twenty five past six
Time: 06:25
It's twenty five past six
Time: 06:26
It's twenty five past six
Time: 06:27
It's around half past six
Time: 06:28
It's around half past six
Time: 06:29
It's half past six
Time: 06:30
It's half past six
Time: 06:31
It's half past six
Time: 06:32
It's around thirty five past six
Time: 06:33
It's around thirty five past six
Time: 06:34
It's around thirty five past six
Time: 06:35
It's thirty five past six
Time: 06:36
It's thirty five past six
Time: 06:37
It's thirty five past six
Time: 06:38
It's twenty to six
Time: 06:39
It's twenty to six
Time: 06:40
It's twenty to six
Time: 06:41
It's twenty to seven
Time: 06:42
It's around quarter to seven
Time: 06:43
It's around quarter to seven
Time: 06:44
It's around quarter to seven
Time: 06:45
It's quarter to seven
Time: 06:46
It's quarter to seven
Time: 06:47
It's about ten to seven
Time: 06:48
It's about ten to seven
Time: 06:49
It's ten to seven
Time: 06:50
It's ten to seven
Time: 06:51
It's ten to seven
Time: 06:52
It's about five to seven
Time: 06:53
It's about five to seven
Time: 06:54
It's about five to seven
Time: 06:55
It's five to seven
Time: 06:56
It's five to seven
Time: 06:57
It's five to seven
Time: 06:58
It's five to seven
Time: 06:59
It's five to seven
Time: 07:00
It's seven o'clock
Time: 07:01
It's seven o'clock
Time: 07:02
It's couple of mins past seven
Time: 07:03
It's couple of mins past seven
Time: 07:04
It's five past seven
Time: 07:05
It's five past seven
Time: 07:06
It's five past seven
Time: 07:07
It's around ten past seven
Time: 07:08
It's around ten past seven
Time: 07:09
It's around ten past seven
Time: 07:10
It's ten past seven
Time: 07:11
It's ten past seven
Time: 07:12
It's ten past seven
Time: 07:13
It's quarter past seven
Time: 07:14
It's quarter past seven
Time: 07:15
It's quarter past seven
Time: 07:16
It's quarter past seven
Time: 07:17
It's quarter past seven
Time: 07:18
It's twenty past seven
Time: 07:19
It's twenty past seven
Time: 07:20
It's twenty past seven
Time: 07:21
It's twenty past seven
Time: 07:22
It's twenty past seven
Time: 07:23
It's twenty five past seven
Time: 07:24
It's twenty five past seven
Time: 07:25
It's twenty five past seven
Time: 07:26
It's twenty five past seven
Time: 07:27
It's around half past seven
Time: 07:28
It's around half past seven
Time: 07:29
It's half past seven
Time: 07:30
It's half past seven
Time: 07:31
It's half past seven
Time: 07:32
It's around thirty five past seven
Time: 07:33
It's around thirty five past seven
Time: 07:34
It's around thirty five past seven
Time: 07:35
It's thirty five past seven
Time: 07:36
It's thirty five past seven
Time: 07:37
It's thirty five past seven
Time: 07:38
It's twenty to seven
Time: 07:39
It's twenty to seven
Time: 07:40
It's twenty to seven
Time: 07:41
It's twenty to eight
Time: 07:42
It's around quarter to eight
Time: 07:43
It's around quarter to eight
Time: 07:44
It's around quarter to eight
Time: 07:45
It's quarter to eight
Time: 07:46
It's quarter to eight
Time: 07:47
It's about ten to eight
Time: 07:48
It's about ten to eight
Time: 07:49
It's ten to eight
Time: 07:50
It's ten to eight
Time: 07:51
It's ten to eight
Time: 07:52
It's about five to eight
Time: 07:53
It's about five to eight
Time: 07:54
It's about five to eight
Time: 07:55
It's five to eight
Time: 07:56
It's five to eight
Time: 07:57
It's five to eight
Time: 07:58
It's five to eight
Time: 07:59
It's five to eight
Time: 08:00
It's eight o'clock
Time: 08:01
It's eight o'clock
Time: 08:02
It's couple of mins past eight
Time: 08:03
It's couple of mins past eight
Time: 08:04
It's five past eight
Time: 08:05
It's five past eight
Time: 08:06
It's five past eight
Time: 08:07
It's around ten past eight
Time: 08:08
It's around ten past eight
Time: 08:09
It's around ten past eight
Time: 08:10
It's ten past eight
Time: 08:11
It's ten past eight
Time: 08:12
It's ten past eight
Time: 08:13
It's quarter past eight
Time: 08:14
It's quarter past eight
Time: 08:15
It's quarter past eight
Time: 08:16
It's quarter past eight
Time: 08:17
It's quarter past eight
Time: 08:18
It's twenty past eight
Time: 08:19
It's twenty past eight
Time: 08:20
It's twenty past eight
Time: 08:21
It's twenty past eight
Time: 08:22
It's twenty past eight
Time: 08:23
It's twenty five past eight
Time: 08:24
It's twenty five past eight
Time: 08:25
It's twenty five past eight
Time: 08:26
It's twenty five past eight
Time: 08:27
It's around half past eight
Time: 08:28
It's around half past eight
Time: 08:29
It's half past eight
Time: 08:30
It's half past eight
Time: 08:31
It's half past eight
Time: 08:32
It's around thirty five past eight
Time: 08:33
It's around thirty five past eight
Time: 08:34
It's around thirty five past eight
Time: 08:35
It's thirty five past eight
Time: 08:36
It's thirty five past eight
Time: 08:37
It's thirty five past eight
Time: 08:38
It's twenty to eight
Time: 08:39
It's twenty to eight
Time: 08:40
It's twenty to eight
Time: 08:41
It's twenty to nine
Time: 08:42
It's around quarter to nine
Time: 08:43
It's around quarter to nine
Time: 08:44
It's around quarter to nine
Time: 08:45
It's quarter to nine
Time: 08:46
It's quarter to nine
Time: 08:47
It's about ten to nine
Time: 08:48
It's about ten to nine
Time: 08:49
It's ten to nine
Time: 08:50
It's ten to nine
Time: 08:51
It's ten to nine
Time: 08:52
It's about five to nine
Time: 08:53
It's about five to nine
Time: 08:54
It's about five to nine
Time: 08:55
It's five to nine
Time: 08:56
It's five to nine
Time: 08:57
It's five to nine
Time: 08:58
It's five to nine
Time: 08:59
It's five to nine
Time: 09:00
It's nine o'clock
Time: 09:01
It's nine o'clock
Time: 09:02
It's couple of mins past nine
Time: 09:03
It's couple of mins past nine
Time: 09:04
It's five past nine
Time: 09:05
It's five past nine
Time: 09:06
It's five past nine
Time: 09:07
It's around ten past nine
Time: 09:08
It's around ten past nine
Time: 09:09
It's around ten past nine
Time: 09:10
It's ten past nine
Time: 09:11
It's ten past nine
Time: 09:12
It's ten past nine
Time: 09:13
It's quarter past nine
Time: 09:14
It's quarter past nine
Time: 09:15
It's quarter past nine
Time: 09:16
It's quarter past nine
Time: 09:17
It's quarter past nine
Time: 09:18
It's twenty past nine
Time: 09:19
It's twenty past nine
Time: 09:20
It's twenty past nine
Time: 09:21
It's twenty past nine
Time: 09:22
It's twenty past nine
Time: 09:23
It's twenty five past nine
Time: 09:24
It's twenty five past nine
Time: 09:25
It's twenty five past nine
Time: 09:26
It's twenty five past nine
Time: 09:27
It's around half past nine
Time: 09:28
It's around half past nine
Time: 09:29
It's half past nine
Time: 09:30
It's half past nine
Time: 09:31
It's half past nine
Time: 09:32
It's around thirty five past nine
Time: 09:33
It's around thirty five past nine
Time: 09:34
It's around thirty five past nine
Time: 09:35
It's thirty five past nine
Time: 09:36
It's thirty five past nine
Time: 09:37
It's thirty five past nine
Time: 09:38
It's twenty to nine
Time: 09:39
It's twenty to nine
Time: 09:40
It's twenty to nine
Time: 09:41
It's twenty to ten
Time: 09:42
It's around quarter to ten
Time: 09:43
It's around quarter to ten
Time: 09:44
It's around quarter to ten
Time: 09:45
It's quarter to ten
Time: 09:46
It's quarter to ten
Time: 09:47
It's about ten to ten
Time: 09:48
It's about ten to ten
Time: 09:49
It's ten to ten
Time: 09:50
It's ten to ten
Time: 09:51
It's ten to ten
Time: 09:52
It's about five to ten
Time: 09:53
It's about five to ten
Time: 09:54
It's about five to ten
Time: 09:55
It's five to ten
Time: 09:56
It's five to ten
Time: 09:57
It's five to ten
Time: 09:58
It's five to ten
Time: 09:59
It's five to ten
Time: 10:00
It's ten o'clock
Time: 10:01
It's ten o'clock
Time: 10:02
It's couple of mins past ten
Time: 10:03
It's couple of mins past ten
Time: 10:04
It's five past ten
Time: 10:05
It's five past ten
Time: 10:06
It's five past ten
Time: 10:07
It's around ten past ten
Time: 10:08
It's around ten past ten
Time: 10:09
It's around ten past ten
Time: 10:10
It's ten past ten
Time: 10:11
It's ten past ten
Time: 10:12
It's ten past ten
Time: 10:13
It's quarter past ten
Time: 10:14
It's quarter past ten
Time: 10:15
It's quarter past ten
Time: 10:16
It's quarter past ten
Time: 10:17
It's quarter past ten
Time: 10:18
It's twenty past ten
Time: 10:19
It's twenty past ten
Time: 10:20
It's twenty past ten
Time: 10:21
It's twenty past ten
Time: 10:22
It's twenty past ten
Time: 10:23
It's twenty five past ten
Time: 10:24
It's twenty five past ten
Time: 10:25
It's twenty five past ten
Time: 10:26
It's twenty five past ten
Time: 10:27
It's around half past ten
Time: 10:28
It's around half past ten
Time: 10:29
It's half past ten
Time: 10:30
It's half past ten
Time: 10:31
It's half past ten
Time: 10:32
It's around thirty five past ten
Time: 10:33
It's around thirty five past ten
Time: 10:34
It's around thirty five past ten
Time: 10:35
It's thirty five past ten
Time: 10:36
It's thirty five past ten
Time: 10:37
It's thirty five past ten
Time: 10:38
It's twenty to ten
Time: 10:39
It's twenty to ten
Time: 10:40
It's twenty to ten
Time: 10:41
It's twenty to eleven
Time: 10:42
It's around quarter to eleven
Time: 10:43
It's around quarter to eleven
Time: 10:44
It's around quarter to eleven
Time: 10:45
It's quarter to eleven
Time: 10:46
It's quarter to eleven
Time: 10:47
It's about ten to eleven
Time: 10:48
It's about ten to eleven
Time: 10:49
It's ten to eleven
Time: 10:50
It's ten to eleven
Time: 10:51
It's ten to eleven
Time: 10:52
It's about five to eleven
Time: 10:53
It's about five to eleven
Time: 10:54
It's about five to eleven
Time: 10:55
It's five to eleven
Time: 10:56
It's five to eleven
Time: 10:57
It's five to eleven
Time: 10:58
It's five to eleven
Time: 10:59
It's five to eleven
Time: 11:00
It's eleven o'clock
Time: 11:01
It's eleven o'clock
Time: 11:02
It's couple of mins past eleven
Time: 11:03
It's couple of mins past eleven
Time: 11:04
It's five past eleven
Time: 11:05
It's five past eleven
Time: 11:06
It's five past eleven
Time: 11:07
It's around ten past eleven
Time: 11:08
It's around ten past eleven
Time: 11:09
It's around ten past eleven
Time: 11:10
It's ten past eleven
Time: 11:11
It's ten past eleven
Time: 11:12
It's ten past eleven
Time: 11:13
It's quarter past eleven
Time: 11:14
It's quarter past eleven
Time: 11:15
It's quarter past eleven
Time: 11:16
It's quarter past eleven
Time: 11:17
It's quarter past eleven
Time: 11:18
It's twenty past eleven
Time: 11:19
It's twenty past eleven
Time: 11:20
It's twenty past eleven
Time: 11:21
It's twenty past eleven
Time: 11:22
It's twenty past eleven
Time: 11:23
It's twenty five past eleven
Time: 11:24
It's twenty five past eleven
Time: 11:25
It's twenty five past eleven
Time: 11:26
It's twenty five past eleven
Time: 11:27
It's around half past eleven
Time: 11:28
It's around half past eleven
Time: 11:29
It's half past eleven
Time: 11:30
It's half past eleven
Time: 11:31
It's half past eleven
Time: 11:32
It's around thirty five past eleven
Time: 11:33
It's around thirty five past eleven
Time: 11:34
It's around thirty five past eleven
Time: 11:35
It's thirty five past eleven
Time: 11:36
It's thirty five past eleven
Time: 11:37
It's thirty five past eleven
Time: 11:38
It's twenty to eleven
Time: 11:39
It's twenty to eleven
Time: 11:40
It's twenty to eleven
Time: 11:41
It's twenty to twelve
Time: 11:42
It's around quarter to twelve
Time: 11:43
It's around quarter to twelve
Time: 11:44
It's around quarter to twelve
Time: 11:45
It's quarter to twelve
Time: 11:46
It's quarter to twelve
Time: 11:47
It's about ten to twelve
Time: 11:48
It's about ten to twelve
Time: 11:49
It's ten to twelve
Time: 11:50
It's ten to twelve
Time: 11:51
It's ten to twelve
Time: 11:52
It's about five to twelve
Time: 11:53
It's about five to twelve
Time: 11:54
It's about five to twelve
Time: 11:55
It's five to twelve
Time: 11:56
It's five to twelve
Time: 11:57
It's five to twelve
Time: 11:58
It's five to twelve
Time: 11:59
It's five to twelve
```

Comment: Sorry for my answer being so vague.
Still, your reply helped me get some great new ideas! Though, I have grasped basics of what is going on, I'm still just a newbie trying my best. Could you please explain what is happening after the $closest = null; line? I struggle to understand this as I have yet to delve into abs values

Comment: np, the $closest lines are getting the closest item in the array by key/index, so for example, if the current minute is 42 the closest one is 43, this is so you don't need to repeat items to cover every minute within the hour.

Comment: See this example: https://3v4l.org/ofEMW